# Memory usage when querying users

Tags: memory

I'm having a small issue with one of my queries here. I cannot increase my wordpress memory limit as long as hostgator sets it to 64mb. I'm not sure if its possible to reduce the amount of memory used making some changes to my code, here is the code I'm using to query users from a specific role and displaying their name, profile and avatar:

```
<?php $users = get_users('role=s2member_level3'); ?> 
<?php foreach ($users as $user) {
    $avatar = get_avatar($user->ID, '96');
    if (get_the_author_meta('description', $user->ID) == "" && stristr($avatar,"gravatar.com/avatar")) { continue; }
    ?>
    <div class="colaborador">
        <div class="imagem-colaborador">
            <?php if ($avatar == "") { 
                echo '<img src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=96" alt="Avatar" />'; 
            } else { 
                echo $avatar;
            } ?> 
        </div>

        <div class="texto-colaborador">
            <h2 class="nome-colaborador"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_author_meta('description', $user->ID);  ?></p>
        </div>                          
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not that I'm a proponent of direct DB access, but if you're running into extreme memory situations, would that be a solution for you? get_users() will cache each "gotten" user in RAM; if you have a buttload of users, this will eat a ton of RAM. You might bypass this with a direct DB query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you are getting all the fields in the get_users call, but you are only really using the ID and display_name fields. So you can save some memory by forcing get_users to only get the fields you need.

```
$users = get_users(array(
  'role'=>'s2member_level3', 
  'fields'=>array('ID', 'display_name'),
));
```

That will help reduce your memory footprint.

Comment: Hey Otto tried your suggestion but the problem persists :/

Comment: You could also save some memory by getting the user_email field as well, and passing that directly into the get_avatar function instead of the user ID.

Comment: Furthermore, your check for $avatar being blank is useless, since get_avatar will *always* return a valid avatar URL. So your call to stristr is also pointless and consumes memory for no reason.

Comment: Hey Otto, just figured it out and removed this line hehe, but the memory problem still there. I also, tried to use pagination but with no success. I`m thinking about changing the default avatar adress, so it will load an image located on my localhost, do you think it will make any difference?

Comment: By the way, is there any way that I can check what is actually using the memory on this page?

Answer (score 1):

#### Call author data

You could change your multiple `get_the_author_meta()` calls against a single `$author_data = get_userdata( $user_id );` call. Then simply extract everything from the object like `$author_data->ID;`. This should save you some memory.

#### Avatar

If you leave out the avatar you will also save a lot of mem. Avatars take a long time to load and use a whole load of memory.

Comment: What about avatar-related functions uses a lot of server memory?..

Comment: I just took a look at how the avatar uses memory (via Chrome dev bar) yesterday. I don't really understand why, but it seemed that there's something about it.

Comment: actually the avatar is the main thing about this page, unfortunatly. But i'll try your suggestion Kaiser, not really sure if it will work though, but lets give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: I do not follow. How does Chrome show PHP memory usage? From quick test `get_avatar()` call increases memory usage by 88 bytes.

Comment: How did you test? I'm completely new to Chrome dev stuff and can't re-do what I tried yesterday. No idea how I found this...

Comment: `xdebug_memory_usage()` before and after (needs xdebug obviously).

Comment: @Vito Argos: So `mem_usage = ~88 bytes x XY users`. How many users do you have?

Comment: Avatars don't use any real memory on the server. That's just in the browser. Don't worry about that.

Comment: Kaiser, I have 61 users, but I'm only displaying those who have avatars attached to their profiles (16), the number will increase with time.

@Otto, so what could be using most part of the memory? By the way, when I remove the avatars the page loads perfectly, all users are displayed.

Comment: When I deactivate my newsletter plugin this message is displayed on the user list page: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 68943872) (tried to allocate 16000 bytes) in /home/organo/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 254

Comment: @Rarst & Otto Thanks for testing, explanation & clarification.